# How to listen for change within a list using flutter provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a provider that is listening for changes to a `playerList` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/constants/PlayerColors.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/models/Player.dart';

class PlayerList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Player> _players = [];

  List<Player> get players {
    return [..._players];
  }

  void addPlayer(Key key, String name, int index) {
    _players.add(
        new Player(key: key, color: PlayerColors.colors[index], name: name));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editPlayerName(String newName, int index) {
    _players[index].name = newName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editPlayerColor(Color newColor, int index) {
    _players[index].color = newColor;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

However, when I call a function to change a value to one of the `Player` objects (change name for example), the list doesn't update the object with new data.

**Do I need another provider for the `Player` class? If so, how do I make the `PlayerList` provider listen for changes in the `Player` provider?**

Doing a little research, I'm thinking ProxyProvider might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Here's my `Player` class if that is helpful:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Player {
  // id will be for database if implemented
  String uid;
  Key key;
  String name;

  //position is the order where the player plays
  int position;
  Color color;
  bool isTurn;
  bool isFakeArtist;
  bool isWinner;

  Player({this.key, this.name, this.color});
}
```

And this is where I create the `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/UserListener.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/models/user.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/providers/PlayerList.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/services/AuthService.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:scam_artist/views/Lobby.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => PlayerList())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: UserListener(),
        routes: {Lobby.routeName: (ctx) => Lobby()},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Have you managed to fix it? I have tried sending the `notifyListeners()` to each object of the list and call it there when I perform my update as well but the behavior still remains. Any ideas?

Also, I am currently using ProxyProvider for other things, and that works correctly, but that is for making one provider listen to changes of another provider, I don't know how to create a dynamic list of providers (Player) to use them that way.

Answer (score 7):

**There are multiple things wrong here.**

**1. Fix your PlayerList declaration line.**

```
//CORRECT
class PlayerList extends ChangeNotifier {...}
```

```
//WRONG
class PlayerList with ChangeNotifier {...}
```

**4. Fix your players getter line.**

Use this:

```
List<Player> get players => _players;
```

**3. You need more Conceptual Knowledge on Provider.**

Basically, Provider makes your PlayerList accessible from anywhere within the Widget Tree below where you have provided it. For example, you are providing from the top of your `MaterialApp`. So you can access it in your `HomePage` or `Lobby`.

To access your `PlayerList`, you have to use a `Consumer` widget or `Selector` widget, but for your case, `Consumer` is enough. `Selector` is for advanced usage.

Here is the code for reading live values from your `PlayerList`.

```
class Lobby extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: _body(),
  );

  _body() => Container(
    child: Consumer<PlayerList>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, PlayerList bloc) => 
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: bloc.players.length,
            itemBuilder: 
               (BuildContext context, int index) => Text(bloc.players[index].name),
          ),
    ),

  );

}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, it seems they want the list model to listen for changes made on the items (player model)

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same problem.

One way I solved it (not the prettiest though) is to have a method in the ChangeNotifier to return a specific object and then watch for changes, e.g.

```
// in ChangeNotifier

Player getPlayer(int index) => _players[index];
```

and then in the widget have

```
context.watch<PlayerList>().getPlayer(index).updateName("newName")
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are modifying from parent PlayerList then this is the way because parent is already notifying in your case**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Player with ChangeNotifier {
  Player({String name, Color color}) {
    this.color = color;
    this.name = name;
  }

  String uid;
  Key key;
  String _name;

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int position;
  Color _color;
  bool isTurn;
  bool isFakeArtist;
  bool isWinner;

  Color get color => _color;

  set color(Color value) {
    _color = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**If you are modifying from within Player and want parent PlayerList to notify**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Player with ChangeNotifier {
  Player({String name, Color color, this.playerList}) {
    this.color = color;
    this.name = name;
  }

  final PlayerList playerList;
  String uid;
  Key key;
  String _name;

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
    notifyListeners();
    playerList.notifyListeners();
  }

  int position;
  Color _color;
  bool isTurn;
  bool isFakeArtist;
  bool isWinner;

  Color get color => _color;

  set color(Color value) {
    _color = value;
    notifyListeners();
    playerList.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change your `_players` accessor and you should be good.

```
  List<Player> get players {
    return _players;
  }
```